# jquery image slider setInterval issue

Tags: jquery, css, slider, setinterval

This is my first use of jquery outside of a textbook so of course I'd have some issues. I have added the code to jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Nq9/3/
Looks like it works on jsfiddle (of course no images on jsfiddle but the alt attribute rotates fine) except when the code runs with the actual images, the 1st image is fine, but when the 2nd and 3rd images rotate my layout goes wonky.
Having looked at the code running in firebug I have noticed that the code changes the css display property. The 1st image, the one that works, changes between display:none and display:inline whereas the other images change between display:none and display:block.
It looks like I need to adjust the code so as to display the remaining images as inline rather than block upon their rotation. I don't know how to do this and would be grateful for and help.

Comment: do you know the width and height of your images? are they all the same or all different?

Comment: @Brian Glaz yes all 3 are the exact same size, 800*235px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to preserve your layout, you'll want to add a width and height to your container div. If a div has no visible content in it, and there is no defined width and height, it won't take up any space on the page, which could cause a layout to break. (the space the div occupied will essentially 'collapse'). This happens because in the case that the image hasn't loaded yet, or the short amount of time in which both images are set as display none, the div won't contain any visible content.

Answer (score 1):

`.show()` sets the following CSS on an element: `display : none`.

So if you want to set `display : inline` then use the `.css()` function instead:

```
elements.first().css({ display : 'inline' });
```

You will have the same issue with `.fadeIn(1000)`, it animates the opacity of the element after setting it's `display : block; opacity : 0`. Try this instead:

```
elements.eq(counter).css({ opacity : 0, display : 'inline' }).animate({ opacity : 1 }, 1000);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Nq9/5/ (you can watch the elements switch between `display : none` and `display : inline`)

Comment: thanks, I altered my code, which still runs with the alteration you suggested but the problem remains - according to firebug images 2 and 3 alter between a display state of none and block, not none and inline. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer about a minute ago, check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Nq9/5/

Comment: thanks a lot that has worked in the sense that firebug is now showing the display alternating between display none and inline but alas it has not, for a reason I dont understand, helped me. The p element below the images dissappears for the 2nd and 3rd image while the footer element jumps up to the middle of the screen. I'm thinking of posting a fresh question. Goodness code is boggling! Thanks for your help though

Comment: Seeing your actual code is necessary at this point. A link to your project would be good, otherwise a jsfiddle with the problem actually exhibiting itself is necessary.

Comment: The problem was with the containing div not having the size set in the end. Thanks for your help and input